# Swift Protobuf Codable Extension

Tags: swift, grpc-swift, swiftprotobuf

We're using Swift Protobuf in a project that generates the message `struct` code (i.e. DTOs). It doesn't implement `Codable` and I'm trying to add `Codable` through an `extension` so that I can serialize them to disk when used inside a non-protobuf that conforms to `Codable`. However, it's quite boilerplate to do this for every `struct`.

Any recommendations on how to minimize the boiler plate code, other than using a static, generic method? Is there a way to do this using generics in the extension definition? Ideally, I'd like to replace `Message1` and `Message2` with a generic extension.

With Swift Protobuf all message structs have a `Message` extension applied, but they do not have a common protocol I can use in a `where` clause for an extension.

```
extension Message1: Codable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let data = try container.decode(Data.self)
        self = try Message1(serializedData: data)
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        let data = try self.serializedData()
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(data)
    }
}

extension Message2: Codable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let data = try container.decode(Data.self)
        self = try Message2(serializedData: data)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        let data = try self.serializedData()
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(data)
    }    
}
```

Comment: A Swift `struct` can conform to `Codable` without any code if all members of the struct conform to `Codable`. Do both `Message1` and `Message2` only have a single property of type `Data`? If so, simply declare an empty extension as `extension Message1: Codable {}`, for example, and you are done.

Comment: @HangarRash Unfortunately, `Message1` and `Message2` have multiple, complex, non-`Codable` properties. I'm serializing the whole object using protobuf's serialization to a `Data`, thus why I used `singleValueContainer`. I'm actually hoping to achieve what you mentioned which would be a generic extension that I can then have a. one-liner to extend each concrete struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, declare a protocol `CodableMessage` that refines both `SwiftProtobuf.Message` and `Codable`. Use an extension to provide default implementations of `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)`.

```
// Use this narrow import to avoid importing SwiftProtobuf.Decoder, since
// that will conflict with Swift.Decoder and generally be annoying.
import protocol SwiftProtobuf.Message

public protocol CodableMessage: SwiftProtobuf.Message, Codable { }

extension CodableMessage {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let data = try container.decode(Data.self)
        self = try Self(serializedData: data)
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        let data = try self.serializedData()
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(data)
    }
}
```

Then, extend each of your generated message types to conform to your new protocol:

```
extension Message1: CodableMessage { }
extension Message2: CodableMessage { }
```

Comment: Thanks, finally got back to where I could give this a try. This might have worked in the same source, but since I'm including the source from another library I'm receiving a "Extension outside of file declaring struct 'Message1' prevents automatic synthesis of 'init(from:)' for protocol 'Decodable'". My understanding is the compiler when it compiles Message1 has no way to know there's another init:from implementation as it's in a different file?

Comment: Are you declaring `extension Message1: CodableMessage`? Just `extension Message1: Codable` will not work for the reason you gave.

Comment: Ahh, that worked, at least I only have to add it for every Message, vs. duplicate the Codable code.